# Bootstrap 3: text on the left and right in the page header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a simple page header with bootstrap 3. Here's the code:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Text on the left</h1>
    <h3 class="text-right">This to the right but on the same line</h3>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle to try: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2450/

Basically I just want to have text on the left and right inside the `page-header`, but **on the same line**.

The usual tricks of using `float:left` and `float:right` as with normal html "break" the `page-header`, meaning the text is properly aligned but is displayed outside (under) the page-header, which remains empty.

Any clues?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

you can use "pull-right" and "pull-left" classes, with "clearfix" class after.

**(Bootstrap 3)**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="pull-left">
  <h1>Text on the left</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
  <h3 class="text-right">This to the right but on the same line</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

also you can adjust line height on the h3 tag in the right, if you want to match with h1

Fiddle for Bootstrap 3: https://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/dy9wjk2q/

**(as of Bootstrap 4.1)**

use `float-left` and `float-right` instead. You still need the `clearfix`.

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="float-left">
  <h1>Text on the left</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="float-right">
  <h3 class="text-right">This to the right but on the same line</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for Bootstrap 4: https://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/eozs65qb/

Comment: All answers worked, chosen this because it's the simplest (doesn't leverage the grid system at all) and the lines properly go one under the other when there isn't enough horizontal space. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why the css in jsfiddle which controls line-height doesn't work when I copy paste into an angular component's .css verbatim?

Comment: @AdamHughes sorry for a late response, first - I just noticed the fiddle isn't working properly because it was created while bootstrap 4 was not out yet, so I updated the external resource to V3 (classes pull-left, and pull-right don't work in V4), can you check which version of bootstrap you are using, next thing is that your line-height property might be overwritten somewhere inside your CSS code, so you can add !important after property - which is not quite good solution, or you can be more specific with targeting the element.
also If you can provide some code example it might be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

if you are using Bootstrap, you should do something like

```
<div class="page-header">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1>Text on the left</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3 class="text-right">This to the right but on the same line</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

if you want to "stylize" the h1, h2, etc, change it to "display:block" and you'll have to add a "width" attribute anyway

Comment: Not sure if this works but this seems to be a more intuitive approach (since OP's question is a typical use case for a grid?) @Master_T

Answer (score 1):

use the following structure to position with bootstrap:

```
<div class= 'container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class ='md-col-4'>
 <h1>Text on the left</h1>
</div>
<div class = 'md-col-4.col-md-offset-4'>
<h3 class='text-right'>This to the right but on the same line</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Think of the row as a grid across of 12. So fist 4 left 3rd. 2nd div is the 3rd third with a 4 grid offset or gap.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: class should be `col-md-4` not `md-col-4`